# Vue.js compatible JS chart for indicating value between a high-low range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, charts, highcharts

I wanted a javascript chart which indicates a value between an upper limit & a lower limit. Real world usage is for indicating current price of a stock between the 52 week High & Low ranges. It also needs to be compatible with Vue.js. I have attached an image below as an example:

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Highcharts site - you can render just a `colorAxis`, hide the rest of the chart and trigger the hover state on point programmatically to display the indicator on the `colorAxis`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/60a4rux7/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed! Is there anyway to indicate the value above the pointer?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy doing it just using CSS!

You just have to enter the percentage where you would like to have your vertical line:

```
<div class="gradient">
  <div class="percentage" style="margin-left:20%" />
</div>

.gradient {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 25%, red 75%);
}

.percentage {
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLrebz7s/

Comment: That's a really nifty way of doing it, thanks! I was wondering if you could also help with adding that tiny arrowhead at the top and the numbers (left, right & one above the arrow?